# How to STOP Chinese birthday calendars

Tags: contacts.app

Chinese calendar keeps showing up when I attempt to add a 2nd birthday to anyone’s contact profile!?  The 1st birthday I add is perfect and in English. BUT... It will not allow me to add any more birthdays to their contact other than using Chinese calendar!

Comment: I don't even see a way to add a second birthday to my contacts, can you detail how you are doing that?